# As3 Anti alias for readibility

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Anyone know how to set a dynamic text box to "antialias for readability"? Heres my code:

```
var t=new TextField();
t.htmlText='<FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="#FF0000">Some Text Here</FONT>'
t.x=200
t.y=300
addChild(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is the [antiAliasType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#antiAliasType) property in conjunction with the [sharpness](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#sharpness) property.

Comment: I've seen this actually but I expected a preset for "readability"? Is the ADVANCED setting the same as enabling readability?

Comment: It is, but you probably should look at sharpness too (link provided in answer)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs for `AntiAliasType`, as this offers further control over the appearance of text in your project:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/AntiAliasType.html

Answer (score -1):

you should create an font in the library, set it to export it for actionscript and then use the textfield.